# .htaccess and $_GET confusion

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have a rather strange situation here. I have a three line .htaccess which is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^/signup/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /signup.php?step=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And a simple algorithm:

```
if (empty($_GET["step"])) 
    { don't do anything } 
else 
    {  if ($_GET["step"] == 'step2')
          { do something } ..
```

Now if I use `signup.php?step=step2` I get an expected result, but if I use `signup/step2/`, `var_dump( $_GET )` returns 0.

I tried all similar threads I found here, but can't find anything working. I might just be walking circles around something I can't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using apache 2.0 or higher, you must strip off leading `/`'s from the pattern, because the rewrite engine strips them off before applying rules in a *per directory* context, and rules in htaccess files are all *per directory* (i.e. the directory the htaccess files are in).

Additionally, if you intend to append a `.php` extension to the end, you *must* check if the file actually exists, otherwise any 404 would lead to a 500 server error. You should also do that *last*:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^signup/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /signup.php?step=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code.

Replace it by this one

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]+)/?$ signup.php?step=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a combination of Jon's and Justin's answers.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]+)/?$ signup.php?step=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```